# ASP.NET - First 2 chars in string must be bold

Tags: asp.net, bold, font-style

I have a table with rows where i have a number in every row. I want this number of rows must be with font-style: **bold**

**This is my code :**

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Route");

int counter = 1;
foreach (SPListItem item in myItemColForTable)
{
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    row["Route"] = counter.ToString() + ". " + item["Route"].ToString();
    counter ++;
}

DataView mydataview = new DataView(table);
table = mydataview.ToTable(true, "Route");
myGrid.DataSource = table;
myGrid.DataBind();
```

I want this string -->

> counter.ToString() + ". "

must be with **bold** style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could pull out the text and replace it with a span with the bold option turned on.

**Example :**

```
void Item_Bound(Object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    string yourSubString = "some string to bold";
    e.Item.Cells[0].Text = e.Item.Cells[0].Text.Replace(yourSubString,
        string.Format("<span style='font-weight: bold'>{0}</span>", yourSubString));

}
```

Comment: this is possible without event ?

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Comment: Share your aspx too.